# SCHEME: Write a function for replacing an element in a list

Tags: list, scheme, lisp

Currently, I'm taking an existing list and replacing either an element or list in the list and returning it using Scheme. Due to constraints of the project, I am only allowed `eq?` for comparison and can't use the `!set` procedure. All of this while using recursion in order to grab potential sublists. The definition order I can't really mess with but overall I'm not receiving what I'm aiming for. For example the case: `(tsar '(x (x) z) '(x) '(y y))` should result in: `(x (y y) z)`.

```
    (define (tsar subj srch repl)
        (if (null? subj)
            subj
            (if (list? (car subj))
                (cons (tsar (car subj) srch repl)          
                    (tsar (cdr subj) srch repl))
                (if (eq? srch (car subj))
                    (cons repl (tsar (cdr subj) srch repl))
                    (cons (car subj) (tsar (cdr subj) srch repl))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The posted code is pretty close to working; as defined in the OP post, the `tsar` procedure appears to work correctly for cases when the item to be replaced is an atom, but not when the item to be replaced is a list:

```
> (tsar '(x (x) z) 'x '(y y))
((y y) ((y y)) z)
> (tsar '(x (x) z) '(x) '(y y))
(x (x) z)
```

Presumably this is what was meant by OP with "*...overall I'm not receiving what I'm aiming for.*" Note that this definition does not work when the item to be replaced is the empty list, either:

```
> (tsar '(x () z) '() 'y)
(x () z)
```

There are two problems here. When a list element is encountered in the list to be transformed, the code recursively descends into that list element to make replacements within; but there is nothing to replace in the list when the item to be replaced is the empty list itself. This is why `(tsar '(x () z) '() y)` does not work. The `car` of the input should be checked against the match *before* attempting to determine if there is a need to descend recursively into an element. This way empty lists can be replaced immediately when matched.

The second problem is the one that OP encountered with the example `(tsar '(x (x) z) '(x) '(y y))`. The trouble here is that `eq?` tests for identity of its arguments, but does not test for structural equality, e.g., list equality. Two lists `'(x)` and `'(x)` are only `eq?` if they are identical objects, which may or may not be the case. But they obviously are the same in the sense that they are lists which contain the same elements. To manage this you should use `equal?`. Here both of these changes have been made:

```lisp
(define (tsar subj srch repl)
  (if (null? subj)
      subj
      (if (equal? srch (car subj))
          (cons repl (tsar (cdr subj) srch repl))
          (if (list? (car subj))
              (cons (tsar (car subj) srch repl)          
                    (tsar (cdr subj) srch repl))
              (cons (car subj) (tsar (cdr subj) srch repl))))))
```

This version works as desired:

```
> (tsar '(x (x) z) 'x '(y y))
((y y) ((y y)) z)
> (tsar '(x (x) z) '(x) '(y y))
(x (y y) z)
> (tsar '(x () z) '() 'y)
(x y z)
```

Now, the post says that `eq?` must be used to solve this problem. I am not sure if this is actually the case, but `eq?` can be used to implement a version of `equal?`. If it is the case that part of the exercise is to implement a version of `equal?`, I would urge the OP to take some time to try and solve this *without* reading further.

Here is a dumb version that gets the job done:

```lisp
(define (my-equal? x y)
  (if (eq? x y)  ; this takes care of atoms
      #t
      (if (or (or (null? x) (null? y))  ; false if either is '()
              (not (and (list? x) (list? y))))  ; false if both are not lists
          #f
          (if (and (list? (car x)) (list? (car y)))
              (and (my-equal? (car x) (car y))
                   (my-equal? (cdr x) (cdr y)))
              (and (eq? (car x) (car y))
                   (my-equal? (cdr x) (cdr y)))))))
```

Note that `'()` and `'()` are always identical objects as far as `eq?` is concerned, and `eq?` always returns `#t` when `symbol=?` would return `#t`. The behavior of `eq?` for numbers and characters is actually implementation-defined; it would be better to use `eqv?` here, but `eq?` should work for our purpose.

In the above definition, first the inputs are checked with `eq?`; if `x` and `y` are `eq?`, then they are identical objects (according to `eq?`), and we are done.

Otherwise if either one of `x` or `y` is the empty list, we should return `#f` (since if they were *both* `'()` then we would have already returned `#t`). One reason for testing against `'()` first is so that we avoid errors when calling `car` or `cdr` on the inputs; in Scheme you cannot call either of these procedures on the empty list.

Or, if *both* `x` and `y` are not lists, we should also return `#f`. Here we are operating under the assumption that any objects of interest that are not lists have already been tested thoroughly enough by `eq?`.

Otherwise, when the `car`s of both lists are lists, we recursively use `my-equal?` to compare those two elements, and use `and` to combine the result of that comparison with the result of comparing the rest of each of the input lists with `my-equal?`.

Otherwise, at least one of the `car`s of the input lists is not a list, so we just use `eq?` to compare the first elements, and use `my-equal?` to compare the rest of each of the input lists.

There are many ways to improve upon the above code. It would be better to use `cond` instead of `if`; it usually seems better to use `pair?` instead of `list?` for this sort of problem, although that doesn't really matter given the way the code is structured. It would be *much* better to use `equal?` instead of writing `my-equal?`.